# Call a REST API apex from Lightning Flow

Tags: apex

I have already created an apex method for a different project. This apex calls an API and parses the response. Here is the Apex class:

```
public static ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp getWipers(String carId, String zipCode){
        
        Client_id = '';
        Client_secret = '';
        getSafeLiteMetaRecord();
        Url_Lite__mdt sfm = mapUrlLite.get(SFDC_EXP_API);
        Client_id = sfm.Client_id__c;
        Client_secret = sfm.Client_secret__c;
        Grant_type_and_scope = sfm.Grant_type_and_scope__c;
        tocken_url = sfm.Tocken_url__c;
        methodType = POST_METHOD_TYPE;

        accesstokenWrap accesstokenWrapObj = getAccessToken();
      
        String endPoint = sfm.Url__c + '/resultapi/parts/wipers/'+carId+'/'+zipCode;
        
        List<ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp> result = new List<ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp>();
        HttpRequest req = CalloutUtility.generateHttprequest(endPoint, GET_METHOD_TYPE);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+accesstokenWrapObj.access_token);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        req.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
        req.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
        req.setHeader('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block');
        result = ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp.parse(CalloutUtility.makeCallout(req).getBody());
        system.debug('result :: '+result);
        
    
        return result[0];
    }
```

Now, I am creating a Lightning flow where I would like to reuse this apex class. The flow will pass the carId and zip to the apex class. I have attempted to write the apex action that lightning flow which will call this REST API but I am not sure if I am writing this correctly and parsing the response properly (The REST API result contains Unit Price and Part Number). Can you please tell me if this is correct?

```
public class Wiper_QuickAction {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Add Wipers to a Work Order' description='Adds a Wiper to an existing work order')
    public static List<ReturnVariables> AddWipers(List<InputVariables> request){
        
        List<String> carId = request.get(0).carId;
        List<String> zipCode = request.get(0).zipCode;
        List<String> partNumber = new List<String>();
        List<String> unitPrice = new List<String>();
        
        for(String cId : carId){
            for(String zip : zipCode){
                ResultAPIs_2Autho.getWipers(cId, zip); //how and what do I do with the result that this method returns. In other words map this to the returnvariables.
            }
        }
        
        ReturnVariables result = new ReturnVariables();
        result.partNumber = partNumber;
        result.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        List<ReturnVariables> resultList = new List<ReturnVariables>();
        resultList.add(result);
        return resultList;
        
    }
    
    public class InputVariables{
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<String> carId;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<String> zipCode;
    }
    
    public class ReturnVariables{
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<String> partNumber;
        
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<String> unitPrice;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? What part isn't working? Do you get any errors?  Please edit your question with more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've got an unnecessarily complicated for loop. You're going to request a matrix of wipers, which is inefficient. For example, given carId A and B, with zipCode 1 and 2, your code would request A+1, A+2, B+1, B+2, which may be overly inefficient.

First, let's create a composite key:

```
class Key {
  String carId, zipCode;
  Key(String carId, String zipCode) {
    this.carId = carId;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
  }
  public Boolean equals(Object other) {
    Key otherKey = (Key)other;
    return carId == otherKey.carId && zipCode == otherKey.zipCode;
  }
  public Integer hashCode() {
    // Just shuffle some bits around to be fairly unique
    return carId.hashCode() << 5 ^ zipCode.hashCode();
  }
}
```

Now that we have this, we'll want to generate a combination of unique values. We'll do this with a `Map<String, Set<String>>`.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> zipCodeToCarIds = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
for(InputVariables var: request) {
  for(String zipCode: var.zipCode) {
    Set<String> temp = zipCodeToCarIds.get(zipCode);
    if(temp == null) {
      zipCodeToCarIds.put(zipCode, temp = new Set<String>());
    }
    temp.addAll(new Set<String>(var.carId));
  }
}
```

After that, we're going to make our callouts:

```
Map<Key, ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp> partResults = new Map<Key, ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp>();
for(String zipCode: zipCodeToCarIds.keySet()) {
  for(String carId: zipCodeToCarIds.get(zipCode)) {
    partResults.put(new Key(carId, zipCode), ResultAPIs_2Autho.getWipers(carId, zipCode));
  }
}
```

Finally, you need to build your response values:

```
ReturnVariables[] results = new ReturnVariables[0];
for(InputVariables var: request) {
  ReturnVariables varResult = new ReturnVariables();
  varResult.partNumber = new String[0];
  varResult.unitPrice = new String[0];
  for(String zipCode: var.zipCodes) {
    for(String carId: var.carIds) {
      Key keyValue = new Key(carId, zipCode);
      ResultAPIs_WipersResponseWrapp zipCarIdResult = partResults.get(key);
      // No idea what the wrapper looks like, so I'm assuming.
      varResult.partNumber.addAll(zipCarIdResult.partNumber);
      varResult.unitPrice.addAll(zipCarIdResult.unitPrice);
    }
  }
  results.add(varResult);
}
return results;
```

Given the API interface, we can't be more efficient than this, but this should be sufficient for small loads, I'd imagine. Performing this logic in bulk is probably a bad idea, given that the API interface can't handle more than a single zipCode/carId pair per call.

Also, I don't know what `getAccessToken()` does, but consider making the token a static variable if you're using callouts to get this token, as you'll save `n-1` callouts if you call this code in bulk.

```
static accesstokenWrap accesstokenWrapObj;


// ... more code here

if(accesstokenWrapObj == null) {
  accesstokenWrapObj = getAccessToken();
}
```